# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for

Tags: mysql

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk1' in the referenced table 'LIBRO'

```
CREATE TABLE libro
  (
     book_id    VARCHAR(5),
     book_name  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     isbn_no    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     cate_id    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     aut_id     VARCHAR(6),
     pub_id     VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
     dt_of_pub  DATE,
     pub_lang   VARCHAR(20),
     no_page    INT(3),
     book_price DOUBLE(4, 3),
     CONSTRAINT primary KEY (book_id)
  );

CREATE TABLE AUTOR(
aut_id VARCHAR(7) ,
aut_name VARCHAR(40),
country VARCHAR(20),
home_city VARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (aut_id),
CONSTRAINT fk1  FOREIGN KEY(aut_id) REFERENCES LIBRO(aut_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replanteo mi respuesta según tu duda, mira lo que ocurre es que para que puedas usar una llave foránea lo primero que debes saber es como ira tu relación, luego crear primero la tabla que será llave foránea, por lo que veo tu relación seria así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo cual deberías primero crear la tabla autor:

```
create table AUTOR( aut_id VARCHAR(7) ,
aut_name VARCHAR(40),
country VARCHAR(20),
home_city VARCHAR(30),
constraint primary key (aut_id)

);
```

Después recién colocar la llave foránea autor dentro de libro:

```
CREATE TABLE libro
  (
     book_id    VARCHAR(5),
     book_name  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     isbn_no    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     cate_id    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     aut_id     VARCHAR(7),
     pub_id     VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
     dt_of_pub  DATE,
     pub_lang   VARCHAR(20),
     no_page    INT(3),
     book_price DOUBLE(4, 3),
     CONSTRAINT primary KEY (book_id),
     CONSTRAINT fk1  FOREIGN KEY(aut_id) REFERENCES autor(aut_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  );
```

Comment: Me confundí, el fallo no me da en la tabla PUBLICACION si no en la tabla AUTOR , lo acabo de actualizar

Comment: Espero te sirva, acabo de actualizar la respuesta.

Comment: Si, muchas gracias